# Syntax for accessing instance variables? (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ivar

What is the proper syntax for accessing an instance variable in Objective-C?

Assume we have this variable:

```
@interface thisInterface : UIViewController {
    NSMutableString *aString;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *aString;
```

and that it is synthesized.

When we want to access it, we first would want to allocate and initialize it.  Having programmed in Objective-C for about a month now, I've seen two different forms of syntax.  I've seen people do simply `aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hi"]`, where they allocate the string like that; I've also seen people start it off with `self.aString` and then they proceed to initialize their ivar.  I guess I'm just trying to figure out what is the most proper way of initializing an instance variable, because with the former example, I have received EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors from it.  After prepending the `self.` though, it didn't appear.

Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, but after reading some posts on SO, it's made me curious.  I'm trying to learn the proper syntax with Objective-C because I prefer being proper rather than sloppy.

Comment: You should use Copy instead of Retain when dealing with strings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have declared a property and `@synthesize` it in the .m file, you simply set it like this:

```
self.aString = @"hi"; // or [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hi"];
```

Using `self.varName` takes advantage of what your property declaration actually does- it handles retention of the new value (since your property has the `retain` attribute), releasing the old value, etc for you.

If you just do:

```
aString = someValue;
```

... you may be leaking the original value that was in `aString`, since without using `self.aString` you are accessing the variable directly vs through the property.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I figured it had to do with something in regards to the retain property.  So when assigning a value to the ivar directly, we don't release the old value (since that's what the `retain` property does, right)? Which can end up causing some leaks.  I just want to make sure that's right before I start analyzing my code.

Comment: Yes, if you modify an ivar directly, you bypass the property's synthesized accessor code.  This can cause leaks, early deallocation, etc.. bad things.  Generally, that's not what you want.

Comment: You do realise that self.aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hi"]; is a leak if the property has a retain attribute....

Comment: I see.  Thanks so much, your explanation was concise and easy to understand! :) And I do agree with @Simon Lee, since it would be retained twice.

Comment: Yep- @Simon Lee is right for if you alloc instead of using an autoreleased convenience method.

Comment: That's not an instance variable, that's a property.  Different things.

Answer (score 12):

Note the difference between `self->varName` and `self.varName`

The first is *pointer* access. The second is *property* access.

Why is that important? Pointer access is direct. Property access, on the other hand makes use of getters and setters (be they `@synthesized` or not). Moreover, as a convenience, the @synthesized accessors take care of the memory mangement for you (i.e. when using `self.varName = ...;`), whereas `varName = ...;` does only what it says, i.e. the assignment -> (there lies the explanation for EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors you might be getting).

Syntactically, both forms are correct. If you want to better communicate intent, use `self->varName` when you want to work directly with the pointer and use `self.varName` when you want to take advantage of the `@property` convenience.

Comment: Excellent outline. Can you please go it a bit in detail about what could go wrong if we just do `varName = ...;`

Answer (score 7):

Here are all the possible combinations (I think)
OKs and BADs are only correct when `aString` property has `retain` attribute:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *aString;
```

So:

#### 1

```
aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //OK:
```

This is OK but only in the case aString is not pointing to an invalid object or you will loose a reference to that object and it will leak because you won't be able to reach it to release it.

#### 2

```
aString = [NSMutableString string]; //BAD
```

Bad because you are suppose to retain aString (as you declared it that way), you are not retaining it and you will get surely get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the future

#### 3

```
aString = [[NSMutableString string] retain]; //OK
```

Same as the first approach, only good if aString is not pointing to a valid object. However I will use the first though.

#### 4

```
aString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];//BAD
```

Same as the second approach.

#### 5

```
self.aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //BAD!!
```

Bad because you are retaining it twice, hence it will lead to memory leaks

#### 6

```
self.aString = [[NSMutableString string]; //******GOOD!******
```

This is probably the safest. It will be retained by the property setter and since you are using the setter any other object that could have been pointed by aString will be released appropriately

#### 7

```
self.aString = [[NSMutableString string] retain]; //BAD
```

This is retained twice.

#### 8

```
self.aString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];//Ok
```

This is also OK, but I would use the convenience method instead of this long approach :)

Be wary that the #1 and #3 options are perfectly good if you know what you are doing. In fact I use them much more frequently than #6

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  I appreciate you listing the different combinations, this helps a lot!  I tend to use #1 the most often, but I didn't realize that 6 would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use the `self.` syntax. It just makes it easier to determine that its an instance variable, and not just some other variable in the current scope that will be lost when its NSAutoreleasePool is drained. However, it is correct to use them both ways, and if you are receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors, it is not because you accessed it without using `self.`. You are correct in saying that you must alloc it, and whichever way you choose to access your variables, keep it consistent or you will receive errors.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Always use accessors except in `init`, `dealloc` and in accessors themselves. Doing this will save you a lot of headaches like the one you're describing. Also, name your ivars something different than your property (`_foo`, `foo_`, `mFoo`, but not `foo`).

`self.foo` is precisely the same as `[self foo]`. I calls the method `foo`. `self.foo = x` is precisely the same a `[self setFoo:x]`. It calls the method `setFoo:`. If you synthesized the property `foo` as a `retain` variable, then this looks something like:

```
@synthesize foo = foo_;

- (void)setFoo:(id)value {
  [value retain];
  [foo_ release];
  foo_ = value;
}
```

This correctly releases the old value of `foo_`, assigns a new one and retains it.

`foo = x` (assuming `foo` is an ivar) does not call any method. None. It just assigns the value of the pointer in `x` to the pointer in `foo`. If `foo` pointed to something that was retained, it's leaked. If the new value you're assigning isn't retained, you'll crash later.

The solution to this is to always use accessors when you can.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great summary, it makes sense.  My Objective-C books/resources really didn't say much about this, which is why I was somewhat confused. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Either.

Using the dot syntax is cleaner (to some) and it compiles to the equivalent. i.e `self.iVar` is the same as `[self iVar]` and `self.iVar = aValue` is the same as `[self setIVar:aValue];`

Comment: Thats not what he was asking, he was questioning whether it should have self in there at all.

Comment: I see.  I've heard though that if you tried doing iVar = aValue, it's incorrect, since it wouldn't be 'setting' the value properly.  Is this true?  I think this was a problem I had, but I never really understood it.

Comment: hmm isn't translated to `[self getIvar]` ?

Comment: No. `self.iVar` is basically `[self iVar]`. `iVar = aValue` is a direct assignment. No `retain` or `copy` happens in a direct assignment.

Comment: @bioffe. KVC requires accessors for `var` to be `-var` to retrieve the value and `-setVar:` to set the value. Cocoa method names with `get` are used to return an value by reference. e.g. `getComponents` from [NSColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Deepak where did I say anything apart from what you said? So why are you saying `no`?

Comment: @Abizern I was referring to @bioffe's statement. But now thinking about it I might've misread his statement too. Sorry about that. Should've tagged whom I was addressing.

Comment: @Deepak - Ah. I see what you mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`self.aString` is a syntactic sugar to `[self aString]`. Synthesize a property just create the `-aString` and `-setAString:` method (depending on the property you have chosen it while not be the trivial affectation).

Now the question is whether to use the `.` notation. I suggest you not to use it.
Why? First know that Objective-C aim to be just an addition to C. This mean that every valid C code is also a valid Objective-C code.

Now look at what they have done with the dot notation. The last statement does not hold anymore. You wont distinguish between an access to a field of a C structure and sending objective-c method.

So please don't use the dot notation. Prefer using the [self ..].